# Map field of Entity with custom Query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I try to create one Entity with fields from two and more tables.
I want to create field with custom Query

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Card")
@SecondaryTable(name = "Account", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "AccountId", referencedColumnName = "CardId"))
public class Card {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "CardId", nullable = false)
   private String CardId;

  @Column(name = "N67ACCN", table = "Account")
  private long numOfAccount;
}
```

For one key `CardId` I have many rows with same `AccountId` and other Columns 
Example,

CardId AccountId AccountPIN

1         1         1

1          1         2

1          1         3

I want something like

```
@Query (value = "SELECT N67ACCN FROM Account WHERE CardId = AccountId and AccountPin = 1")
private long numOfAccount;
```

}

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you.

You miss `()`

```
@Formula("(SELECT DISTINCT n.N67ACCN FROM N67 n WHERE n.N67MBID = B31AGID AND n.N67ACGN = 1)")
private String numOfAccount;
```

and use only name of Columns (not fields\properties)

Answer (score 0):

You need [Hibernate @Formula](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/Formula.html)

```
@Formula ("SELECT N67ACCN FROM Account WHERE CardId = AccountId and AccountPin = 1")
private long numOfAccount;
```

But I suppose that you need `SELECT COUNT` if you expect `long` value.